# infura.io secret configuration in HDWalletProvider (truffle-config.js)

Tags: truffle, infura, truffle-config

I have set a secret for my project in infura.

Here is my truffle-config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    ...
    ropsten: {
      provider: new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://ropsten.infura.io/xxxxx"),
      network_id: 3
    }
  }
};
```

My question is: Where can i put secret in this configuration file. I have read a lot of documentation/turorials and there is nothing about this secret.

Thanks a lot

Comment: did you figure this out? I have the same issue, current answers don't seem to understand the question in the first place

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error I've found a way to make this work. Not sure if this is the only way or the best, but here it goes:

```
const provider = new HDWalletProvider(process.env.WALLET_MNEMONIC, `https://:${process.env.PROVIDER_SECRET}@rinkeby.infura.io/v3/${process.env.PROVIDER_ID}`);
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
```

Notice how there's a `:` before the secret and a `@` after. This works because Infura expects this as a basic auth with no username, only password, which is the secret.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use something like a .env file to secure your project secret and keep it from being seen. Alternatively, you could take an approach similar to what this user did for their

Comment: This is not what the question asks. The question is, how do you actually use the secret so that it's sent to infura.

Answer (score 0):

Make a .env file in the same folder:

```
MNEMONIC="Your MNEMONICs"
INFURA_URL="Your Infura URL with API key"
```

Then replace the truffle-config.js code with this:

```
const HDWallet = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
const mnemonic = process.env.MNEMONIC;

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    kovan: {
       provider: () => new HDWallet(mnemonic, process.env.INFURA_URL),
       network_id: process.env.NETWORK_ID,       
       gas: 5500000,        
       confirmations: 0,    
       timeoutBlocks: 200,  
       skipDryRun: true     
     },
  },
```

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what i have done in my real project. I have removed env var stuff for my question. but there  is no infura secret in your answer...

Comment: Go to infura.io, after that you can signup and get the secret.

Comment: I have the secret ! What i want to do is to know how i can set this secret in truffle-config.js

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the Project secret, this is an optional value for authenticating and securing your HTTP traffic to Infura. This option is disabled by default and not needed by truffle. Is there a particular reason why you would need to truffle to connect to infura in this way?

Comment: I would like to configure this secret in truffle for security reasons. I don’t want someone to use my infura account

Comment: Infura docs even say that's an additional protection you should use if you can secure the secret.